# Disagrees about version error when inserting sctp.ko

Tags: module, arm, kernel, sctp

Unable to insert sctp.ko after cross compiling the module against the  same version of kernel sources.

The sctp.ko was not available as part of NXP board(ARM machine). So I cross compiled and generated sctp.ko with reference to resident kernel source code (used to build kernel image) for this board.

I had to enable support for SCTP module in the menuconfig of the kernel source to be able to build sctp.ko.

make -C path to lib/modules/5.10.35-00078-gf5c40f10d25e/build M=$PWD modules

However when I tried to modprobe sctp , I am getting below errors (alot of such errors in dmesg)

[735781.646640] sctp: disagrees about version of symbol release_sock

[735781.646642] sctp: Unknown symbol release_sock (err -22)

[735781.646645] sctp: disagrees about version of symbol skb_queue_head

[735781.646647] sctp: Unknown symbol skb_queue_head (err -22)

Unable to understand why there is a version issue because I used 5.10.35-00078-gf5c40f10d25e to build and thats running on the arm machine.

Note:Tried building the kernel after changing the SCTP option to M and it created a sctp.ko. Getting same errors when I try to insert sctp.ko module.

Please advise if I am missing something.

Comment: Can you build as non-module?  Does it pull in extra modules.  sctp may depend on other code which is also not in the build.  For instance, `skb_queue_head` is an inline function, in the source I have.  Is your compiler supported?  Also, I thought I had to pass some defines to cross-build, but maybe you have a .config that is handling this.  Is it possible you have a different gcc version?